# How to use string tokenizer on an array?

Tags: string, tokenize

I see that you can't use string tokenizer on an array because you cant convert `String()` to `String[]`.  After a length of time I realized that if the inputFromFile method reads it line by line, I can tokenize it line by line.  I just don't know how to do it so that it returns the tokenized version of it.

I'm assuming in the `line=in.ReadLine();` line I should put `StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(line,",")`.. but it doesn't seem to be working.

Any help?  (I have to tokenize the commas).

```
public class Project1 {

    private static int inputFromFile(String filename, String[] wordArray) {
        TextFileInput in = new TextFileInput(filename);
        int lengthFilled = 0;
        String line = in.readLine();
        while (lengthFilled < wordArray.length && line != null) {
            wordArray[lengthFilled++] = line;
            line = in.readLine();
        }// while
        if (line != null) {
            System.out.println("File contains too many Strings.");
            System.out.println("This program can process only "
                    + wordArray.length + " Strings.");
            System.exit(1);
        } // if
        in.close();
        return lengthFilled;
    } // method inputFromFile

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] numArray = new String[100];
        inputFromFile("input1.txt", numArray);
        for (int i = 0; i < numArray.length; i++) {
            if (numArray[i] == null) {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(numArray[i]);
        }// for

        for (int i=0;i<numArray.length;i++)
        {
            Integer.parseInt(numArray[i]);
        }

    }// main
}// project1
```

Comment: Once each line is read, call split method. String [] tokens = line.split(","); then append this array into wordArray and increment counter.

Comment: @UsmanSaleem I try to add the line but then it says that tokens is never being called on.  Where exactly should I enter that code, and can you please let me know how to append it into the wordarray?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I meant:

```
while (lengthFilled < wordArray.length && line != null) {
            String[] tokens = line.split(",");
            if(tokens == null || tokens.length == 0) {
                 //line without required token, add whole line as it is
                 wordArray[lengthFilled++] = line;
            } else {
                 //add each token into wordArray
                 for(int i=0; i<tokens.length;i++) {
                     wordArray[lengthFilled++] = tokens[i];
                 }
            }

            line = in.readLine();
}// while
```

There can be other approaches as well. For instance, you can use a StringBuilder to read everything as one big string and them split it on your required tokens etc. The above logic is just to point you in right direction.